# Is there anything wrong with await Task.Run(() => semaphore.WaitOne())?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

Title says it all. Is there anything wrong with `await Task.Run(() => semaphore.WaitOne());`? `System.Threading.Semaphore` isn't thread-affine, so I wouldn't think there would be a problem. I know that the `SemaphoreSlim` class is available, but I need to do cross-process synchronization, and `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't do that.

Or can/should I create my own custom type of `WaitHandle`?

Comment: There is technically no problem doing this. Whether you should do this or not depends on many more details not specified in your post.

Comment: The underlying operation is inherently asynchronous, and yet you're having a thread pool thread synchronously wait on the asynchronous operation so that you can asynchronously indicate when you're done.  This is generally poor design, and should be avoided if possible.  It's a sign that you probably shouldn't be using `Semaphore` in the first place.

Comment: This indicates either a mistake on your part or a questionable design. I suspect the former - you say you "need to do cross-process synchronization" but this isn't really going to synchronize anything. If the process calling `WaitOne` actually needs to know when the semaphore is signaled, why doesn't it wait synchronously? If it doesn't need to know, why have the semaphore at all?

Comment: For brevity in the title, I omitted `await`ing the resultant `Task`. I would have something like:

`await Task.Run(() => semaphore.WaitOne()) /* Do work */`
or
`await Task.Run(() => { semaphore.WaitOne(); /* Do work */ })`

Comment: Define "wrong".  Short answer is: yes, for broad definitions of "wrong".  It could be that you're using semaphore in the wrong way--based solely on what you've posted it looks more like named event would be better.  `WaitOne()` waits indefinitely, what happens if the app tries to exit before the semaphore is signaled?  What happens if the semaphore becomes abandoned?  You're not handling exceptions. Etc...

Comment: What kind of app is this? Phone? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to keep the UI responsive while waiting for the semaphore here, it might make sense, but there's a catch: *["Semaphores don't have owners"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/23/496248.aspx)*. If you share the semaphore between two processes, and the other process crashes without calling `Semaphore.Release()`, **the ownership over the shared resource will be lost**. The remaining process may not be able to acquire it again.

IMO, the [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) semantic would be more appropriate here, but with `Mutex` you'd need thread affinity. Perhaps, you can acquire the mutex, access the resource and release it on the same thread:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        // use the shared resource
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex(); 
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunnning);
```

If that's not possible (e.g., because you need to access the shared resource on the main UI thread), you could use a dedicated thread for the mutex. This can be done with a custom task scheduler, e.g. Stephen Toub's [`StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) with `numberOfThreads:1` (the helper thread doesn't have to be made STA in this case):

```
using (var scheduler = new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1))
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => mutex.WaitOne(), 
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        scheduler);
    try
    {
        // use the shared resource on the UI thread
    }
    finally
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => mutex.ReleaseMutex(), 
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            scheduler).Wait();
    }
}
```

**Updated**, if you're concerned about WinRT (i.e., [.NET for Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx)) or Windows Phone, then `Task.Factory.StartNew` w/ `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is still there, you can use it instead of `new Thread()` with `StaTaskScheduler` or something like my [`ThreadWithSerialSyncContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23016220/1768303) whenever you need a background thread with affinity.

Comment: Nice solution, but I don't think it works for me. I can't use a `Mutex` because I need to await some tasks while I have acquired the semaphore, and so thread-affine locks are a no-go. Using `Wait()` or `RunSynchronously()` also is not an option. The `StaTaskScheduler` solution you proposed sounds good, but unfortunately, in the latest iteration of the WinRT APIs, the `Thread` class is nonexistant. Barring a hard reset of the system (which would clear the semaphore anyway), if I wrap the synchronized code in a try/finally, would there be any possibility of an abandoned semaphore?

Comment: @ZaneKaminski, if you carefully balance `WaitOne`/`Release` with `try`/`finally` everywhere, you should be fine with this approach.

Comment: @ZaneKaminski, also check my update regarding WinRT.

Comment: Great idea. I didn't even think about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SemaphoreSlim(0, 1)` WITH your `Semaphore` , and `WaitAsync` before waiting for your original semaphore. This would ensure that for each process, only one thread is blocked waiting for the original `Semaphore`, and the others, while (a)waiting for `WaitAsync`, is not blocked.

Another solution is to use the exclusive scheduler of `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`.